# Open JSP Page directly in brower using URL

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am using Apache-Tomcat-7 and I placed a jsp page( `myjsp.jsp` ) in

```
...\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\desktop\
```

I have started the tomcat and trying the following URL to open the jsp page

```
http://localhost:8089/desktop/myjsp.jsp
```

But it is giving **404**. I donot want it to open through other means. Can any body tell me that what I am doing wrong?

P.S. localhost:8089 works fine for other applications and tomcate is configured to this port-8089.

**EDIT**

When I placed the `myjsp.jsp` in `ROOT` folder under

```
...\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ROOT\
```

and try

```
http://localhost:8089/myjsp.jsp
```

Now it works. So what is the reason that in the desktop folder the jsp was **NOT** found

**OR**

how can I access `myjsp.jsp` if it is placed within `desktop` folder?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve doing that?

Comment: Did you deploy it at root context or you didn't at all or you have nothing to deploy?

Answer (score 0):

Well one way is the way you have already done (by deploying it at the root context of the tomcat server). Although it would seem to work fine, I won't recommend doing that. Changing root context of tomcat to some other application/pages is for other purpose.

The best way to do is to create a small project (you need a dynamic web project with a proper deployment descriptor --> eclipse will do all this job by just a button click), then deploy this project to your tomcat server.

So lets say if you create your project as MyProjectOne, then just place your JSP page (lets call it test.jsp) under `WebContent` or `src/main/webapp` folder and you will be able to view your page as `http://localhost:8089/MyProjectOne/test.jsp`

Comment: Yeah I know that I can do this ... But right now I donot want to make project in eclipse ... Just want to know that from URL how to access it ?

Comment: There will just be hacks and work-arounds but in the end they will all be using (or mocking) a project. Tomcat needs atleast a deployment descriptor and proper hierarchy of your project structure so that it can decide what to do with your JSP files that you put in.

Comment: Then why it runs in ROOT ?? in the `ROOT/Web-inf/web.xml` I didn't change the path to my jsp... So you are trying to say that there should be a `web.xml ` in each project/folder ?

Comment: Yes but ROOT is already a proper project with the deployment descriptor and all, so when you place your JSP inside that folder, the tomcat notices the change and deploys that JSP. The only difference with ROOT is that since its a root context project, you don't have to write the name of this project in the URL. Thus you see as tomcat has directly deployed the jsp, when in reality it has not done without using the context of the ROOT project